# how to return the word "by" + link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a helper method which does this

```
def show_username(username, id)
    if username == "Global_User"
      "anonymously"
    else
      link_to username, profile_path(id)
    end
end
```

but, i want to return the word "by" before the link_to username. The problem is when I put "by " + link_to it breaks, and i cant use a do block on the link because thats the text inside the link (i dont want the word by to be a part of the link)

I'm calling it like

`<%= show_username(resource.user.username, resource.user.id) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def show_username(username, id)
    if username == "Global_User"
      "anonymously"
    else
      raw("by ") + link_to(username, profile_path(id))
    end
end
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
      "by".html_safe + link_to username, profile_path(id)

Comment: yeah, updated it. I've updated my post to use `raw` instead. use `html_safe` only when you're sure the caller isn't nil, so here I could also use that.

Comment: and be careful with `html_safe`, it unescapes all potentially dangerous html. one of the solutions to this could have been `("by " + link_to(username, profile_path(id))).html_safe` but this is very dangerous.